# Reading PuTTY output with c#

Tags: c#, windows, io, putty

**What i want:** I want to read the Output of the PuttY Window with C#

**What I've got:** Our company has several hundreds of servers with at least 2-3 technical users (which are running applications). We got a database of all the users and passwords. So it's basically search, copy and paste to login.

**What i want to do:** Write a piece of software that does this automatically.

**How far i am:** Wrote a tool, that reads the logfile of a single PuTTY instance and looks for the password prompt. Determinates target user and server (based on current server and su - [username]). Retrieves the password and sends it via PostMessage to a selected PuTTY.

**The Problem or what i want to change:**

I want to be able to read the PuTTY output directly from the PuTTY window, because the logfile is kind of unreliable (TAB, ESCAPE, etc which scrambles the output).
I have used UISpy and other tools to get a control, but no luck.

I don't want to use a keylogger mechanism or something like that.

Maybe a hook or something, but have never done that before.

**Additonal Info:**

- Connection is made over a JumpServer, only ssh connections from there to the target servers are allowed.
- Direct login with the tech. user is disabled.
- The PuTTY window is already opened and used to work on the server.
- Writing a whole new Connection Manager is no option. Coworkers are familar with PuTTY and this solution should be some sort of standalone background worker.

**Additonal Info 2:**
The goal is to write a strict 3rd party software. Not to use other SSH libs, modify PuTTY source or other approaches. The question is: how to read text from the PuTTY window, beside the logfiles.

Comment: Why don't you start putty with the `-l` and `-pw` arguments? http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#3.7.3

Comment: You could find an SSH library and write your own client with password manager.

Comment: @Albin Sunnanbo: Working with arguments won't work here. The initial connection of putty it to a "jump server" from which connections to the target servers is allowed. Also, direct login with the tech. users is disabled.

@ Alan: writing my own app with lets say sharpssh would be possible. but all workers here use putty and are familar with it. so my appraoch was minimal invasive

Comment: @mazer , I had similar problem , but I wrote simple IPC which allows me to request putty to copy specified rectangle of text in clipbaord using window messages.Then I simple read clipboard.If you're interested I can post my code.Note that you need to recompile PuTTY from source, but it's simple.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET

Comment: This doesn't help you directly, but you're looking for something equivalent to EHLLAPI for PuTTY.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why this hasn't been suggested yet, but plink (which is part of the PuTTY suite) is the command-line version of PuTTY, you'll just need to redirect stdin and stdout to get a relatively powerful (as in features, you'll still need to interpret telnet stuff yourself) SSH client.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using OCR?

Sketch of solution would be:

1 - Agent runs waiting to notice a Putty Window (either register a callback with OS for new processes or periodically check the list of running processes)

2 - When a putty is noticed, agent takes screenshot and extracts portion of screen occupied by putty. You would need to extract window location, but can be done via OS calls assuming you have a handle from step 1

3 - Pump this image data into [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) or something, and get text output back. check to see if the password prompt is there

4 - If prompt is there, it sounds like you had the rest done after this (send info needed via PostMessage)

Comment: I will take a look at OCR. Process Watcher and handle are present (needed for PostMessage). Thanks for the link, have to see how this affects the overall performance.
Currently messing around with MS Detours, DLL injection and hooks, which sounds promising. Nevertheless i will try the OCR approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [This Link (Putty StdIn / StdOut](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c14d5871-28c9-4bfc-a56d-d3d3a50395f4). Shows how to open putty from a c# app  and how to handle Standard In, Out and Error Output to communicate with your putty instance.

Comment: Thanks, this link is very helpful for the future but won't apply to my problem. The PuTTY window is already opened and used for further work on the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using putty as an SSH tool, use http://www.routrek.co.jp/en/product/varaterm/granados.html C# SSH library

If you are using putty as a serial tool use the inbuilt IO classes

Telnet also has C# libraries, none that I can give any knowledgabel input into what is good.

Answer (score 0):

If you can purpose a modified version of putty, you should modify putty sources and including some pipes (or socket) that communicates with your c# application. Like that, your coworker keep the same software.

Comment: This would work, but dosn't solve my problem here. The goal is to do this with an unmodified PuTTY.